# How to read CSV into React Native State Array?

Tags: reactjs, csv, react-native

I have a question re: how to load data from CSV into an array in React -- specifically inside the this.state as an object.

Lets say I start with this, where the state is just hardcoded values.

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cards: [
        {itemname: 'Item 1',
          restoname: 'Resto 1',
          url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/grubhub/image/upload/v1515191165/bkf4niv9okipbc8y6o8h.jpg',
          description: 'Desc 1'},
        {itemname: 'Item 2',
          restoname: 'Resto 2',
          url: 'https://res.cloudinary.com/grubhub/image/upload/v1514060352/twhriy3hvbzayktrjp91.jpg',
          description: 'Desc 2'}
      ]
    };
  }
```

Is there a way for me to read in that data instead from a CSV where the data is like this?

[image]

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Try this npm package. This will help you convert `csv` to `json` which you can easily use in your react component - https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson

```
import csv from 'csvtojson';
const csvFilePath='<path to csv file>';
csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.on('json',(jsonObj)=>{
    // combine csv header row and csv line to a json object
    // jsonObj.a ==> 1 or 4
})
.on('done',(error)=>{
    console.log('end')
})
```

Comment: Hey I am getting error can't find variable csv. Can you please help to resolve it?

Comment: you need to import it

Comment: yes i  did that, but after that i am getting another eror  \node_modules\\csvtojson\\v2\\Converter.js","targetModuleName":"stream","message":"Unable to resolve modulestream

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use the `csvtojson` on the React Native environment.
It works in node but didn't work on Expo, and I think for the RN is the same.

If you just need data from local, then convert CSV into JSON and import it. No extra library needed.
I think this is the easiest.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59746430/1593212