# CSV preview in React native

Tags: android, ios, json, csv, react-native

I am new to react-native. I am trying to fetch data from csv file placed in my local folder.

- -I have added     `"csvtojson": "^2.0.4",` in my `package.json` file.
- -run `npm i --save csvtojson` command as explained [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson)

Also i check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48759265/how-to-read-csv-into-react-native-state-array) answer but nothing worked fine for me.
With below code i am getting error `CSV` is undefined. I added `import csv from 'csvtojson';` i my component then it starts showing error stream not find under `\node_modules\\csvtojson\\v2\\Converter.js","targetModuleName":"stream","message":"Unable to resolve module`stream

Here's is the code i am using

```
const csvFilePath='../img/test_csv_file.csv';

csv()
.fromFile(csvFilePath)
.on('json',(jsonObj)=>{
    // combine csv header row and csv line to a json object
    // jsonObj.a ==> 1 or 4
})
.on('done',(error)=>{
    console.log('end')
})
```

Please correct me where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In react-native your code does not run on a Nodejs platform so if a library uses a native node module/library it will not run successfully.

There are libraries for using node modules in react-native, you can check those out or you can try to find a react-native library that does what you want to achieve.

Comment: Not that I know of also suggestions are off-topic in SO. Do a google search and I'm sure you will find lots of information.