# React Native: Can not import csv file

Tags: react-native

I have a **csv** file located at `./src/data` folder and I wish to import it to be able pass to **papaparse library** to be parsed to **JSON** library. This is the script I use to do that

```
import Papa from 'papaparse';
import file from './src/data/test.csv';

const test = () => {
    console.log( "start parsing" );

    Papa.parse( file, {
        download: true,
        complete: result => {
            console.log( "result:", result.data );
        }
    });
};

export default test;
```

I get this error:

> Unable to resolve module ./src/data/test.csv

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't import CSV file directly.

This will not work

```js
import dataCSV from './data.csv'
//or
const dataCSV = require('./data.csv')
```

So I ended up using an online converter to convert CSV to JSON and imported it.
I think this is the easiest solution when you just need a specific file to load.

```js
import dataJSON from './data.json'
```

There are some libraries to handle such a situation but I didn't want to add extra library.

Comment: how to write to csv file? I have a json data which needs to be exported as .csv file

Comment: google "json csv converter", it seems like there are many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately loading static assets is a bit convoluted in react native.

1. First you need to tell the bundler (Metro) to bundle the files of interest, create a `metro.config.js` file in your root with this:

```js
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config');

const configs = getDefaultConfig(__dirname);
configs.resolver.assetExts.push('csv')

module.exports = configs;
```

you probably need to `npm i @expo/metro-config` as well.

2. Now using [Expo Asset](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/) (`npx expo install expo-asset`) you have to download the file of interest from the bundle to the file system, so you can get access to it:

```js
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";

const { localUri } = await Asset.fromModule(require('/src/data/test.csv')).downloadAsync();
```

3. And using [Expo FileSystem](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/) (`npx expo install expo-file-system`) you can load your file content and parse it

```js
import { readAsStringAsync } from "expo-file-system";
import Papa from "papaparse";

const csvString = await readAsStringAsync(localUri);
                
Papa.parse(csvString, {
        complete: result => {
            console.log( "result:", result.data );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

- Hello ,

  UPDATE: You must first import the file, just as you would a
  component.

```
import myDataset from '../path/to/myDataset.csv';
Papa.parse(myDataset, {
  download: true,
  delimiter: '\t',
  complete: function(results) {
    console.log(results);
  }
});
```

Specify a config value for download as true. Delimiter should be auto-detected, as per Papa Parse documentation.