# Problem with a CSV file in React Native. Undefined Unable to resolve module `./assets/race.csv`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm trying to convert a CSV file to JSON in an Expo RN project however when I try to import the CSV file   I get this error -

```
undefined Unable to resolve module `./assets/another.csv` from `App.js`:
```

None of these files exist:

```
assets\another.csv(.native|.android.expo.ts|.native.expo.ts|.expo.ts|.android.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.android.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.android.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
```

Is there a way to work with CSV files in RN at all. What if I want the user to be able to upload a CSV file with the DocumentPicker, then convert it to JSON and save to a database ? Is that possible

Comment: [This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55144828/7704650)

Comment: not very useful. I need the user to upload the csv from the phone file system and then convert it to JSON and show the results to the UI